# How to perform this nested while true loop?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

```py
def add(fm_list):
    while True:  
        msg = input("What do you want to create?: "
                    "\n Insert 1 for Folder "
                    "\n Insert 2 for Subfolder.\n")
        if msg == "1":
            folder = input("Name of the folder: ")
            choice = input("Do you want to add a subfolder to this folder?: (y/n): ")

            if choice.lower() == "y":
                # ... do things ...
                break
            elif choice == "n":
                # ... do things ...
                break
            else:
                print("Please choose between (y/n)\n")

        elif msg == "2":
            store = input("Where do you want to store your subfolder?: "
                          "\n Insert A to store it in the DEFAULT folder"
                          "\n Insert B to store it in a new folder\n")
            if store.lower() == "a":
                # do things ...
                break
            elif store.lower() == "b":
                # do things ...
                break
        else:
            print("Invalid entry!!!\n")
            continue
```

Thanks in advance for the answers.
I have my function `add()` here, I would like when I hit the stage of the `elif msg == 2`... when the user inputs anything else other than the available options (a or b) then he gets prompt back to choose the appropriate option (In other words, I give the hand again and ask the user where to store the subfolder) ... instead it does prompt back at the beginning of the code.

```
msg = input("What do you want to create?: "
                    "\n Insert 1 for Folder "
                    "\n Insert 2 for Subfolder.\n")
```

...Thanks

Comment: Redacted 90% of the code, it is completely irrelevant for the question and makes it highly unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Well after some time and some help I finally get to do what I wanted 
we created a recursive function (not sure if this is it is called tho) then call it back later on the add function:....

```
        def getstore(fm_list):
            store = input("Where do you want to store your subfolder?: "
                          "\n Insert A to store it in the DEFAULT folder"
                          "\n Insert B to store it in a new folder\n")
            if store.lower() == "a":
                subfolder = input("What is the name of the subfolder: ")
                fm_list.append(subfolder)
                print("Your subfolder will be store to the Default folder: ")
                os.chdir('F:\\Test\\Default')  # this is the Default folder already in the test directory
                os.makedirs(subfolder, exist_ok=True)
                print(subfolder + " was added to the folder named Default")
                quit()
            elif store.lower() == "b":
                folder = input("Name of the folder: ")
                fm_list.append(folder)
                os.chdir('F:\\Test')
                os.makedirs(folder, exist_ok=True)
                subfolder = input("Name of the subfolder: ")
                fm_list.append(subfolder)
                os.chdir('F:\\Test\\' + folder)
                os.makedirs(subfolder, exist_ok=True)
                print(folder + " was added to the list of folder.")
                print(subfolder + " was added to " + folder)
                quit()
            else:
                getstore(fm_list)
```

then later when we get to the `elif msg == "2"` we call `getstore(fm_list)`
just like this...

```
 elif msg == "2":
                getstore(fm_list)
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid entry!!!\n")
                continue
```

And that's it.